# Iterating over lists in Haskell do block?

Tags: haskell, blaze-html

I apologize for the bad title, but I don't quite know how to summarize this.

I'm a Haskell beginner, making a website in Haskell (Hakyll) using templates in Blaze-HTML, which uses do notation to make HTML. Here's part of my template:

```
defaultTemplateRaw :: Html
defaultTemplateRaw = html $ do
    H.head $ do
        meta ! httpEquiv "Content-Type" ! content "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        H.title "My Hakyll Blog - $title$"
        link ! rel "stylesheet" ! type_ "text/css" ! href "/css/main.css"
        link ! rel "stylesheet" ! type_ "text/css" ! href "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        link ! rel "stylesheet" ! type_ "text/css" ! href "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
```

Now let's say I wanted to be DRY here, so I wouldn't have all the `link`s, just a list of URLs in some kind of list comprehension. How would I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `mapM_` here:

```
thelinks :: [AttributeValue]
thelinks = ["list", "of", "hrefs"]

defaultTemplateRaw :: Html
defaultTemplateRaw = html $ do
    H.head $ do
        meta ! httpEquiv "Content-Type" ! content "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
        H.title "My Hakyll Blog - $title$"
        mapM_ ((link ! rel "stylesheet" ! type_ "text/css" !) . href) thelinks
```

So here we use [**`mapM_ :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m ()`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM_) to process the monadic function `((link ! rel "stylesheet" ! type_ "text/css" !) . href)` for every element of the list `thelinks`.

We construct the function by using [*operator section*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator), so:

```
(link ! rel "stylesheet" ! type_ "text/css" !)
```

is equivalent with:

```
\x -> link ! rel "stylesheet" ! type_ "text/css" ! x
```

But we can not directly pass an `AttributeValue` as `x` to that function: we need to use the `href` attribute, we do so by using `. href`, thus thus means that:

```
  (link ! rel "stylesheet" ! type_ "text/css" !) . href
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
= (\x -> link ! rel "stylesheet" ! type_ "text/css" ! x) . href
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
= \y -> (\x -> link ! rel "stylesheet" ! type_ "text/css" ! x) (href y)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
= \y -> (link ! rel "stylesheet" ! type_ "text/css" ! (href y))
```

So it is a more syntactically convenient way to call the `href` function on the item of the list, and that result in the structure of `link ! ...`.

For the given sample list, this produces:

```
Main L R> putStrLn $ L.unpack $ R.renderHtml defaultTemplateRaw
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><title>My Hakyll Blog - $title$</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="list"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="of"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hrefs"></head></html>
```

Comment: Awesome. Although could you explain a little more why are `link` and `href` broken up like that?

Comment: @Jono: I added a short explanation.